# coefficients of polynomial and binomial expressions

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients

Let us say we are given a polynomial p(x)=$\sum_k a_k x^k$. In order to find $\sum_k a_k$ we simply need to evaluate p(1), and similarly there are many other tricks. Is there any trick to evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} a_k$?

Comment: No there aren't